# PowerShell modify date column in csv

Tags: powershell

I have a series of csv statements from my bank that I would like to combine and pull out the relevant rows. I have managed to get the rows out, but for the date column I would like to reformat the date from DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM to YYYY-MM-DD and I can't Google up the concept of how I should do this? I'm a PS noob.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction please?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv 

$output = ForEach ( $file in $files ) {
    Import-CSV $file | Where-Object{$_.Description -eq "Funding Bacs" -or $_.Description -eq "Lender Withdrawal Request" } | Select-Object Date,Description,"Paid In", "Paid Out" 
    # foreach of the date fields, take the date object? string? remove the time, and reformat the date to YYYY-MM-DD 
} 

$output | Export-Csv Newtest.csv -NoTypeInformation -encoding "unicode"
```

Current Output:

```
Date             Description               Paid In Paid Out
----             -----------               ------- --------
03/04/2012 09:15 Funding Bacs              50.0    0.0
06/04/2013 17:32 Lender Withdrawal Request 0.0     234.5
01/04/2014 05:31 Funding Bacs              125.0   0.0
01/04/2014 05:31 Funding Bacs              10.0    0.0
```

Desired Output:

```
Date             Description               Paid In Paid Out
----             -----------               ------- --------
2012-04-03       Funding Bacs              50.0    0.0
2013-04-06       Lender Withdrawal Request 0.0     234.5
2014-04-01       Funding Bacs              125.0   0.0
2014-04-01       Funding Bacs              10.0    0.0
```

Update: thanks to Martin I'm now getting the below... need to figure out why I'm getting the missed date values.

```
Date             Description               Paid In Paid Out
----             -----------               ------- --------
2014-03-11 Funding Bacs              10.0    0.0
2014-03-11 Funding Bacs              125.0   0.0
           Lender Withdrawal Request 0.0     521.05
2016-07-11 Lender Withdrawal Request 0.0     188.93
           Lender Withdrawal Request 0.0     185.57
2012-03-10 Lender Withdrawal Request 0.0     148.72
2013-01-10 Funding Bacs              460.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **calculated property** where you format the date. Just change the `Select-Object` to:

```
Select-Object @{l="Date"; e={(Get-Date $_.Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')}},Description,"Paid In", "Paid Out"
```

Comment: That's working pretty much as I wanted, thanks. Getting some missed date values in the output... my input date data appears to be consistent, so not sure why I'm getting this, I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: Hm, I think you have to provide the sample data

Comment: Ahh, they're all the ones with the date starting with a number >12, it might be failing to read the date correctly for UK date format styles? I'll read some more on your calculated properties and Get-Date. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason. So probably take a look how to correctly parse datetimes in PowerShell, the rest should be fine.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. The datetime parse bit works on a single date string of the same format, but in my whole line it doesn't work. I'm close, but my understanding of Powershell isn't good enough yet. Import-CSV $file | Where-Object{$_.Description -eq "Funding Bacs" -or $_.Description -eq "Lender Withdrawal Request" } | Select-Object @{l="Date"; e={(Get-Date [datetime]::Parse($_.Date, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("En-GB"))).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')}},Description,"Paid In", "Paid Out"

Comment: Can you provide some Test Data to reproduce the issue?